# How to write a query to compare current date to created_at timestamps in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to write a query to compare created_at timestamp with my current date in Ruby on Rails using ActiveRecord and I don't quite know how do it yet

Date is stored like this -> created_at: 2019-06-03 03:30:40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% if @user.created_at > 5.days.ago.beginning_of_day %>
  <span>New User!</span>
<% end%>
```

Or you can use:

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@user.created_at) %>
```

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward in Ruby

`@user.created_at > Time.now`