# How to compare only the date from a DateTime attibute with a Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Article.where(created_at: result)
```

`created_at` is DateTime, `result` is an array of Dates

How can I compare only date from `created_at` with `result`?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452130/10895713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
Article.where("Date(created_at) IN (?)", result)
```

Comment: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: ...= '2019-01-02' AND selected_at <= '2019-04-07') AND (Date(crea...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."article_id" = '10'  AND (Date(created_at) = '2019-01-05','2019-01-12','2019-01-19','2019-01-26','2019-02-02','2019-02-09','2019-02-16','2019-02-23','2019-03-02','2019-03-09','2019-03-16','2019-03-23','2019-03-30','2019-04-06') LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count excluded from capture: DSN not set

Comment: This is what i got if i try Article.where("Date(created_at) = ?", result)

Comment: this is result :[Sat, 05 Jan 2019, Sat, 12 Jan 2019, Sat, 19 Jan 2019, Sat, 26 Jan 2019, Sat, 02 Feb 2019, Sat, 09 Feb 2019, Sat, 16 Feb 2019] , if i change from Date in DateTime will look like this [Sat, 05 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000, Sat, 12 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000, Sat, 19 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000, Sat, 26 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000, Sat, 02 Feb 2019 00:00:00 +0000], BUT in Article.where(created_at: result) will not select the good ones because time differs. (ex: Article.created_at -> Thu, 04 Apr 2019 09:37:09 UTC +00:00 )

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by this

`Article.where(created_at: result.midnight..result.end_of_day)`

or

`Article.where(created_at: result.beginning_of_day..result.end_of_day)`

result.midnight will convert date object to DateTime object with starting time and end_of_day will give us the end of the day time, and then we can create a range for that day.

Comment: this is result :[Sat, 05 Jan 2019,
 Sat, 12 Jan 2019,
 Sat, 19 Jan 2019,
 Sat, 26 Jan 2019,
 Sat, 02 Feb 2019,
 Sat, 09 Feb 2019,
 Sat, 16 Feb 2019] ,  if i change from Date in DateTime will look like this [Sat, 05 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000,
 Sat, 12 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000,
 Sat, 19 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000,
 Sat, 26 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000,
 Sat, 02 Feb 2019 00:00:00 +0000],  BUT in Article.where(created_at: result)  will not select the good ones because time differs. (ex: Article.created_at -> Thu, 04 Apr 2019 09:37:09 UTC +00:00 )

Comment: oh, result is an array of date objects?